# Spring Boot - Create Entity classes as Jar (or plugin)

Tags: plugins, spring-boot, dependencies

I need to create few services that will read from single database. All these services needs entity to read from DB. Instead of creating same Entity class in all services, I want to create a package (jar or similar to grails plugin), which contains all Entity classes. So that all other services use the package with Entity class as dependency.

Note: I know how to create as grails plugin and to use in grails app. I wondering is there any way similar to that in spring boot.

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with Spring boot? Just create a separate module/project with your entities and add it as a dependency to your Spring boot project(s)?

Comment: I wasted an entire day trying to separate out my Entity classes and Repository classes into their own jar and ended up giving up.  I can't believe that there is no interest in this.  With the spread of microservices, it seems that having a jar with all Entity classes - at the very least - would be common.